# How to specify the color of text rendered to a PDF in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, pdf-generation, core-graphics

Do you know how to change the color of text rendered to a PDF document created using Core Graphics (via UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile, etc)? We are currently rendering text to the document via UIKit category methods on NSString, such as drawInRect:. I don't see any methods that allow text color to be specified. I need to draw some gray text, but currently all of the text is black.

I would prefer to keep it simple and use UIKit to do this, but I'm open to using Core Graphics functions if that's the only way.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't e.g. `[[UIColor redColor] set];` do it?